# How to make the application display correctly on various screens?

Tags: flutter

The application looks good on a Pixel 4 XL (resolution of 1440 x 3040) but is overflowing on a Samsung A5 (720 x 1280).

I expected the components to be scaled based on the resolution/ppi, but it seems that I misunderstood.

So how can I fix this ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Comment: If you don't hardcode any width, code all in fluid/relative width, and fix some bugs with the help of Expanded/Flexible/AutoSizeText, you don't need any lib

Comment: You can Achieve this through MediaQuery

Comment: @Jscti can you please point me to some tutorials or articles on how exactly to achieve that ? The only hardcoded things that I can think of in my app are paddings and text size.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving a great looking UI on different screen sizes is to size your widgets relatively to the screen size, and not with pixel amounts, since when the screen's width or height is smaller or bigger, and the widgets are the same size, the UI will either go out of bounds or you will have empty spaces in your UI.

**how to achieve that:**

in your build function you can store the screen size in a variable:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  ...
```

then in your widgets that you are returning in the build function, for example a container, change the pixel values to values relative to the screen size:

instead of

```
return Container(width: 50, height: 70);
```

write stuff like:

```
return Container(width: screenSize.width * 0.1,
 height: screenSize.height * 0.12);
```

Comment: I don't use fixed sized containers. What I use is padding with fixed size and text size. I assumed those would be relative to the screen size, but it seems I was mistaken. Can you please give me examples for those 2 cases ? Thanks.

Comment: In both padding sizes and text sizes you also need to use sizes relative to the screen size, you can use exactly the same method i explained here, in text sizes i recommend going based on the screen's width not height

Comment: You can try the `sizer` package.

Comment: @RazGino MediaQuery.of(context).size doesn't return the size of the screen though. And I am not sure how I can use those values to get the value of the text.

Comment: try for example:
int text_width = screenSize.width / 20
and change it up until your text seems right, let me know if you have any problems